# Return generic list from generic function with C++/CLI

Tags: c#, generics, c++-cli

I am trying to write a generic function in C++/CLI which will be creating a generic list. The type parameter of the list is the same as the type of the generic function.

In **C#** I simply do this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MyClass
{
    static List<T> CreateList<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

In **C++/CLI** I try to do the same, i.e.

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

generic <typename T>
List<T>^ MyClass::CreateList ( void )
{
    return gcnew List< T >();
}
```

but all I get is a compile error:
**error C2371: 'list' : redefinition; different basic types**

What am I doing wrong?

Note: the actual function will be doing more things than just creating a list but this is where I get stuck.

**EDIT:**
Hi guys, thanks for the replies

apparently the error I was getting was misleading. I created a new solution containing only (apart from main() ) MyClass, and got a different error. Then I tried Hans Passant's code and magically it worked. Looking again the only difference I could see, was that I was fully qualifying the List type
i.e. System::Collections::Generic::List instead of List (however I omitted that in my previous earlier post for clarity). It turns out that the compiler for some reason does not like that. i.e.

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

generic <typename T>
System::Collections::Generic::List<T>^ MyClass::CreateList()
{
    //return gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<T>;   // this gives compile error
    return gcnew List<T>;   // this is all right
}
```

I don't know if this is a bug or there is a reason for it...
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Where is the compile error *exactly* and what is the function declaration in the class itself?

Comment: Had a similar error. Removing the explicit namespace worked for me too. Compiler bug I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to guess at the source of that error message.  The L in "list" isn't capitalized, make sure you are not getting into trouble with the std::list template class.  Make sure that a previous class declaration *before* the method isn't missing a semicolon.  Anyhoo, correct code would look like this:

class declaration:

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

ref class MyClass
{
public:
    generic <typename T>
    static List<T>^ CreateList();
};                                    // <== note semi-colon here.
```

method definition:

```
generic <typename T>
List<T>^ MyClass::CreateList()
{
    return gcnew List<T>;
}
```